# Why does siri pop up when testing new iOS 14 widget?

Tags: swift, siri, widgetkit

Like the title says, I'm testing widgets locally on a simulator. I have xcode 12, seed 6. On an iPhone 8 simulator.

Upon a fresh install, prior to the widget being installed on the home screen, Siri pops up despite me not having intentionally triggering it. I'm not aware of any code that would be able to trigger it either. Any suggestions on why this is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The scheme that I was using was originally intended to handle the WidgetKit Intent configuration. So in the scheme itself, it had a "Siri Intent Query" inside the run step. So all I had to do was create a new scheme that was intended to test the Widget, and the query was no longer there. It then ran without triggering it.